# SQL - Where In one table not the other (Multiple Fields)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables

[image: Tables]

Their Relationship is the following: modulos holds all modules, and mods_alunos holds only the modules each student made(nInterno identifies the student)

```
    select modulos.codDisc, modulos.numero from modulos
    left join mods_alunos
    on modulos.codDisc=mods_alunos.codDisc
    and modulos.numero=mods_alunos.numero
    where 
    (mods_alunos.codDisc is null 
    and mods_alunos.numero is null
    )
```

This query gives the modules missing but doesnt take the student into account

I'm looking for a query that list the modules a certain student is missing

EDIT 1 - Sample Data

Modulos

```
codDisc | numero
------- | ------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 2
```

mods_alunos

```
nInterno | codDisc  | numero
-------- | -------- | ------
11       | 1        | 1
11       | 1        | 2
11       | 1        | 3
11       | 2        | 1
12       | 2        | 2
```

With this example what i want is a query that gives me (codDisc 2, numero 2) when i ask what modules is student 11 missing

Comment: your question is not clear ...can you add some sample data and desired output to make it understandable

Comment: What you have been trying is an anti join. I don't recommend using it, when a simple `EXCEPT` or `NOT IN` does the job. Use anti joins only when you actually run into performance problems with the straight-forward methods. As to the issue: You'd have to add `and mods_alunos.ninterno = 123` to your `ON` clause in order to find the modulesstudent 123 is lacking.

Comment: Seems to me like `mods_alunos` is a linking table between `Student` and `Modules`, if you what to get all modules that a student is missing, you will need to work off of the Student master table. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to work from your Student table, not the linking table. try this:

```
select s.Id, m.codDisc, m.numero 
from student s
cross join modulos m
where not exists(select *
                 from mods_alunos ma 
                 where ma.codDisc = m.codDisc 
                 and ma.numero = m.numero
                 and ma.nInterno = s.Id)
```

Where `student` is your student table, and s.Id is your Student ID

Comment: just to clarify can you explain why you used cross join and not a different join?

Comment: @Cacheira a cross join gets all modules per student, then on the where clause you exclude the ones that are already linked.

Comment: @Cacheira: The query gives you *all* students with their missing modules. As you only want to know which modules a particular student is missing, you don't need this.

Comment: By the way: does `TOP` work for MySQL? I thought you must use `LIMIT` there. And anyway it's superfluous and should be omitted, so as to have the DBMS find the optimal execution plan itself.

Comment: I made some changes to the query: changed top 1 1 to * and added a couple and's i needed on the end of the where and got the result i needed

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** `EXCEPT is not supported by MySQL.

<strike>Simply use `EXCEPT`:</strike>

```
select coddisc, numero from modulos
except
select coddisc, numero from mods_alunos where ninterno = 123;
```

`NOT IN` would be an alternative, though slightly more complicated, so I'd go with `EXCEPT` as mentioned.

```
select coddisc, numero from modulos
where (coddisc, numero) not in
  (select coddisc, numero from mods_alunos where ninterno = 123);
```

Comment: tried the except and it gave me an error "[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select codDisc, numero from mods_alunos where nInterno = 1' at line 3"

Comment: Ah, sorry, `EXCEPT` is one of the standard features that MySQL doesn't support. Well, then `NOT IN` *is* the easiest approach in MySQL unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM modulus WHERE codeDisc NOT IN(SELECT codeDisc  FROM mods_alunos WHERE nInterno=?) AND numero NOT IN (SELECT numero FROM mods_alunos WHERE nInterno=?
```

Comment: I want simply where codDisc is missing i want when the codDisc and numero combination is missing